# How to disable autocomplete for Struts tags(HTML:text)

Tags: struts

For normal HTML input tag,disabling autocomplete is simple as given below:

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Whereas its does not work for Struts tags given below:

```
<html:text property="" styleId="Field" maxlength="4" size="4" tabindex="14" 
    onblur="check(this);" value="" />
```

How to disable autocomplete for Struts tags?

Comment: What version of Struts? You can always modify the TLD to allow dynamic attributes to pass through, IIRC, although I thought it already did that. I don't recall as S1 is pretty old now.

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete attribute is not passed through to the rendered HTML by the  tag.

You can do so by writing your own custom tag that extends the  tag to accept the autocomplete attribute and pass it through to the rendered  tag.

check these links ::

[Struts 2 + Disable Form Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030628/struts-2-disable-form-autocomplete)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/54020/Struts/form-input-tags-turning-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same issue. Editing the tld attibutes did not help me. I resolved it by adding the attribute via JavaScript code. Here is an example:

```
<bean:define id="autoComplete" scope="request" type="java.lang.String"
    value="<%=String.valueOf(ApplicationConfiguration.getAutoComplete()) %>" />

<script>
    var ttip;
    var ttip2;
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        var form = document.forms['formName'];
        var elem = form.elements["passortField"];
        elem.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "${autoComplete}" );
```

`ApplicationConfiguration.getAutoComplete()` - returns either `on` or `off`, depending on application configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redisplay="false"` which is the equivalent in `struts-html` for autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write your Own TextTag class something like this:

```
public class TextTagNoAutoComplete extends BaseFieldTag {
    public TextTagNoAutoComplete() {
         super();
         this.type = "text";
         doReadonly = true;
    }
    protected void prepareOtherAttributes(StringBuffer handlers) {
         prepareAttribute(handlers, "autocomplete", "false");
    }
}
```

and point textnac to this class in your tld mapping! ..and Viola ! Not the best reusable code. Provided the fact that, Struts 1.x is in no way going to be revisited, this sortta monkey patching is more than enough in my point of view :)

Answer (score -1):

We can use the attributes which are not supported in `<htm-text>` inside \"

```
<html:text property="userName" styleId="firstname\" placeholder=\"Email*\" 
           autocomplete=\"off" styleClass="ql-inpt"  readonly="true" />
```