# How to disable autocomplete off in struts

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(":input").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```

i tried this but some browser(opera)not supported.please help me to solve this error

Comment: Read [How to disable autocomplete for Struts tags(HTML:text)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322853/how-to-disable-autocomplete-for-struts-tagshtmltext) and follow the links.

Comment: hi Braj am using struts1.2

Comment: Have you followed the [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/54020/Struts/form-input-tags-turning-autocomplete)?

Comment: yes.but that one is for struts2

Comment: So you have read it till the end?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace in your JSP the Struts 1.x tag:

```
<html:text property="usr" styleClass="minimalist" size="10" maxlength="15" />
```

With the equivalent HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="usr" class="minimalist" size="10" maxlength="15"
                          │
                          └───── Form property ────┐
                                                   │
       value="<bean:write name="MyForm" property="usr" />" autocomplete="off" />
                                   │                
              Name of form-bean ───┘
```

The value of the attribute `name` of the HTML input tag must match the property of your `ActionForm` (e.g. `usr`) in order to Struts 1.x *populate* the value in that form. If the value of the attribute `value` of HTML input tag (the actual text show it in the control) is optional, you can forget the `bean:write`.